# Applescript to copy files based on partial file name

Tags: applescript

Forgive me, I'm a bit of an amature.

I'm working to comply with a records request for hundreds of students. All files are named with the first 5 digits of the name being the student's ID number. I created the script below and it runs but with no results.

I would welcome any help that you guys can provide.

```
with timeout of 3600 seconds
tell application "Finder"
    set myFiles to files of folder POSIX file "/Volumes/Storage/Records" as alias list
end tell
repeat with aFile in myFiles
    tell application "System Events"
        set myvalues to {"11111", "22222", "33333", "44444", "55555", "66666", "77777", "88888", "99999", "00000", "11112", "22223", "33334", "44445", "55556", "66667", "77778", "88889", "99990"}

        if name of aFile contains myvalues then
            copy aFile to folder POSIX file "/Volumes/Storage/Records"
        end if
    end tell
  end repeat 
end timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the command to copy files in terminology of Finder and System Events is `duplicate`.

Second of all (and the main issue) you have to check the first 5 characters not the entire name.

And third of all, it’s not quite useful to copy the files to the same place but I guess it’s only a placeholder

```
property IDNumbers : {"11111", "22222", "33333", "44444", "55555", "66666", "77777", "88888", "99999", "00000", "11112", "22223", "33334", "44445", "55556", "66667", "77778", "88889", "99990"}

with timeout of 3600 seconds
  tell application "Finder"
    set myFiles to files of folder "Storage:Records:"
    repeat with aFile in myFiles

      set IDPrefix to text 1 thru 5 of (get name of aFile)
      if IDPrefix is in IDNumbers then
        duplicate aFile to folder "Storage:Records:Destination:"
      end if
    end repeat
  end tell
end timeout
```

My solution uses only the Finder because it doesn't include the invisible files and it's not needed to coerce the Finder object specifiers to alias.

If the location of the files is on an external volume, it’s easier to use the HFS path `“Storage:Records”` than the coercion from POSIX path `POSIX file "/Volumes/Storage/Records” as alias`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use **do shell script** function instead of using Finder application as it's more flexible solution. And you can find any errors in your command easily because you can debug it using the Terminal.

```
do shell script "<your commands here>"
```

For your use case you need to use a couple of commands inside do shell script: **find** and then **cp**.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simple `bash` script is a better option here. Save the following script on your Desktop as `CopyFiles`

```
#!/bin/bash
# Make a subdirectory to copy the results to
mkdir results 2>/dev/null

# Read all ids from file "ids.txt"
while read id; do
   echo Processing id: $id
   # Remove the word "echo" on following line to actually copy files
   echo cp /Volumes/Storage/Records/${id}* results 
done < ids.txt
```

It assumes there is a file on your Desktop called `ids.txt` that looks like this

```
11111
22222
12345
54321
```

Then start a Terminal, by pressing Cmd+Spacebar and typing "Terminal" and hitting "Enter".

Go to your Desktop and make the script executable with

```
cd Desktop
chmod +x CopyFiles
```

and then run it with

```
./CopyFiles
```

At the moment, it does nothing except tell you what it would do like this:

```
Processing id: 11111
cp /Volumes/Storage/Records/11111* results
Processing id: 22222
cp /Volumes/Storage/Records/22222* results
Processing id: 12345
cp /Volumes/Storage/Records/12345* results
Processing id: 54321
cp /Volumes/Storage/Records/54321* results
```

If it looks like it is doing what you want, edit the script and remove the word `echo` where noted and run it again.